# How to create selecting option UITableView similar in iOS Settings in Swift?

Tags: php, ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm developing an app that requires users to select one option from the list of the table view. It's kind of similar to ringtone option in settings of the iPhone. I have attached a screen illustration of what exactly I'm trying to accomplish.

Now I want that option that is selected to be able to send as a value to my PHP Script with `HTTPMethod`. This is the type of request I use, I guess, is just in matter of storing the data in variable.

**HTTP Request Demo**

```
   let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/script.php")
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
```

**Illustration:**
[image]

I understand this is a beginner, but I haven't found any tutorial that does this in swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this can be done using segue

1. You just need to click a button or a cell in tableview to go to next viewController.You can use `show segue`
2. When use select the cell,fire an `unwind segue` to go back. And use the unwind segue to pass data back.
3. Update model and UI with the data passed back.

Comment: OK I may give you an example using storyboard,give me a moment

Comment: Hi Brian, I found that if I answer you with Screenshot.That will cost too much space. I found a similar toturial for you.http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2

Answer (score 0):

This is done using navigation controller and UITableView.

The top bar with the 2 buttons is preset because of navigation controller.

In the navigation controller, a grouped UITableView is used with the header "alert tones" and the cells being the name of the tones.

This is a **video tutorial which uses both navigation controller and UITableView**. Also this tutorial is in swift. https://itunesu.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/LZDirectory.woa/ra/directory/courses/961180099/feed

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down a sample codes.
Check this out.

If you have questions, ask me whenever you want.

**MainViewController**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, ListViewControllerProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var button:UIButton?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func toList() {
        var listViewController = ListViewController(nibName: "ListViewController", bundle: nil)
        listViewController.delegate = self
        self.pushViewController(listViewController, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        self.toList()
    }

    func onSelectObj(obj:NSDictionary) {
        // set data to button
    }
}
```

**ListViewController**

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView?

    var delegate:ListViewControllerProtocol?

    var identifier = "ListViewController"
    var data = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView?.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)

        self.updateData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 37
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        var row = UInt(indexPath.row)

        var obj = self.data[0] as! NSDictionary
        cell.textLabel?.text = obj["name"]

        return cell;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        var obj = self.data[0] as! NSDictionary
        self.selectObj(obj)
    }

    private func selectObj(obj: NSDictionary) {
        self.delegate?.onSelectObj(obj)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    private func updateData() {
        // Code for getting data

        self.data = someDeserializedData

        self.tableView!.reloadData() // reload!
    }
}

protocol ListViewControllerProtocol {
    func onSelectObj(obj:NSDictionary)
}
```