# Select item from list in another view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a **Select state** button. When user click to it, he see new table view with list of states. When he select one, he go back to previous view(it has a navigation bar controller) and button name changed to selected state.

I understand the principle i create a segue where send `selectedState`, but how to go back with selected value i don't know. And have another bug

[image]

Table view selects two cells. Here is my code:

```
class StateTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let selectedState:String = "AZ"
    let states = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA",
        "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD",
        "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ",
        "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC",
        "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.states.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.states[indexPath.row]

        if (self.states[indexPath.row] == self.selectedState) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

This question is similar [How to create selecting option UITableView similar in iOS Settings in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586142/how-to-create-selecting-option-uitableview-similar-in-ios-settings-in-swift)

but i don't understand it :(

Comment: You need an `else` clause that sets the accessory to none if it isn't the selected state. How are you triggering the return to the previous scene?  Via the "back" button on the navigation controller?

Comment: You can use an unwind segue to pass the data back to the previous controller. This tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2) has a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a quick example for delegation where `MainViewController` is the first viewcontroller that contains a `selectStateButton` and `StatesViewController` is the tableviewcontroller that opens after tapping the button presenting a list of states. feel free to ask if you have any questions:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, StateSelector {
  @IBOutlet weak var selectStateButton: UIButton!

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Select state" {
      if let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController, let statesViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? StatesViewController {
        statesViewController.delegate = self
        statesViewController.selectedState = (sender as? UIButton)?.titleForState(.Normal)
      }
    }
  }

  func didSelectState(state: String) {
    selectStateButton.setTitle(state, forState: .Normal)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
}

protocol StateSelector {
  func didSelectState(state: String)
}

class StatesViewController: UITableViewController {
  var delegate: StateSelector?
  var selectedState: String?

  let states = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA",
    "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD",
    "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ",
    "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC",
    "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return states.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.states[indexPath.row]

    if (self.states[indexPath.row] == self.selectedState) {
      cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    } else {
      cell.accessoryType = .None
    }

    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    delegate?.didSelectState(states[indexPath.row])
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not working;( It shows state list ok, but when i click on any cell protocol function doesn't call ```didSelectState``` function. my full code: http://pastebin.com/AuPCcS0U
http://pastebin.com/4utbeDTU

Comment: can you show me a screenshot of your storyboard please?

Comment: ah, yes i changed my segue kind to ```Present Modally``` and it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unwindSegue(segue:UISegue)` or in case of using `prepareforSegue` providing to the destination VC itself as a delegate.